# How to implement logarithm with continued fraction in Racket?

Tags: racket

The log-approx inputs an integer n and approximate log such that the value return is from computing the first n terms of the series. An sample output is `((log-approx 100) 0.75)` returns a number close to -1.38629.

My idea is to use continued fraction to approximate log. But my code doesn't return the desired output.

The code I have so far.

```
(define (cont-frac n x k)
  (define (iter result count)
    (if (= count 0) result
        (iter (/ (n count) (+ ( x count) result))
              (- count 1))))
  (iter 0 k))

(define (log-approx n)
  (cont-frac (lambda (i) -1.0)
             (lambda (i) n)
             100))
```

This is what I got: `(log-approx 0.75)   ; outputs 1.56467792561282`
But it should be -1.38629.

**Edit: I forgot to mention the formula for the series. 
`-log(1 - x)` can be approximated as the sum of terms `(x^k)/k`, with k running from 1 up to n, the approximation improves as n increases.**

Comment: What base are you using to obtain `-1.3862`? `log(0.75)` returns `-0.1249` in base `10` and `-0.2876` in base `e`.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I forgot to mention that -log(1 - x) can be approximated as the sum of terms (x^k)/k. So, - log(1 - 0.75) = 1.38629.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write the `cont-frac` procedure to match the given formula (why the `lambda`s? they just return constant values!). Also pay attention to the result calculated by the continued fraction: it's `-log(1 - x)`, so we have to adapt `log-approx` for it. This should work:

```
(define (cont-frac n k)
  (define (iter k acc)
    (if (zero? k)
        acc
        (iter (sub1 k) (+ (/ (expt n k) k) acc))))
  (iter k 0))

(define (log-approx n)
  (- (cont-frac (- 1 n) 100)))
```

For example:

```
(log 0.75)
=> -0.2876820724517809
(log-approx 0.75)
=> -0.2876820724517809
```